# How do I use TMUX, with python3

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, debian, tmux

So I want to open a new terminal, like every hour and run a command, but I am worried that if i open a new terminal then run the command, the command won't be ran on the new terminal but on the old one.

I am a beginner so any help will be appreciated

Comment: Unless the command is interactive, it doesn't need a terminal at all.

Comment: You can use `crontab` (normal tools for such task, installed on every system, because it is used also by Debian itself). Such program will open a new shell and it execute the command inside such shell (but without terminals, it will send you a mail with "terminal output", and I think also an error if the program try to read input)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need an instance of TMUX? You can pretty much just use *Popen* from the *subprocess* module and run commands from there by doing `Popen("netstat", stdout=PIPE)` for example.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

pipe = Popen("ping -c 4 8.8.8.8", stdout=PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
text = pipe.communicate()[0]
print(text)
```

Comment: Probably prefer `subprocess.run` like the documentation for `Popen` already mentions.

Comment: you are my hero